# Header file not found of one private repo inside another private repo on pod spec lint

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

Suppose I am creating a private repo A, In private repo I have another two repos B and C. B and C are having Objective-C files. The respective files of pod B and C are imported in B.h and C.h.
Both B and C are working fine. When I try to use in pod repo A, header files of B and C are not finding during pod spec lint.

Comment: Is repo A in Swift?

Comment: Repo A is having both objc and swift code